# Error en json y ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, codeigniter-3

Este es mi error:

> DataTables warning: table id=table - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

Estoy utilizando *Codeigniter*.

Lo que pasa es que a un data table le cargo los datos con *Ajax* haciendo una consulta a la base de datos.

Hasta ahí todo bien, pero esa consulta la quiero hacer dinámica dejando al usuario seleccionar un ID y fechas que las mando por *Ajax* para crear búsquedas con esos parámetros.

Este es el código con el que relleno mi tabla:

```
$('#table').DataTable({
'paging': true,
'info': true,
'filter': true,
'stateSave': true,

  'ajax': {
    "url":baseurl+"index.php/reports/getPersonas/",
    "type":"POST",
     dataSrc: ''
  },
  'columns': [
    {data: 'iUsuario'},
    {data: 'Agente'},
    {data: 'Cliente'},
    {data: 'Disposition'},
    {data: 'FechaIns'},
{"orderable": true,
 render:function(data, type, row){
    return   '<a href="#" class= "btn btn-block btn-primary btn-sm"></a>'

      }
    }
   ],
  "order": [[1 , "asc" ]],
});
```

Después en el formulario creo un botón y los datos de fechas y ID si los envío correctamente al controlador desde la vista, pero cuando recibo la respuesta me sale el error antes mencionado.

```
$('#submit').click(function(){

var agente          =   $('#agente').val();
var dateone         =   $('#dateone').val();
var datetwo         =   $('#datetwo').val();
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/reports/getPersonas",
        data:{
            'agente':       agente,
            'dateone':      dateone,
            'datetwo':      datetwo
        }, 

        success:function (data) {
            alert("Los datos fueron agregados con exito");

        },error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log('error:: '+ errorThrown);
        }

    });
});
```

Mi vista

```
                    <h2>Buscar</h2>
                    <!-- <form method="get" id="frm" class="form-inline" action="form_x_editable.html">  -->
        <?php echo form_open('reports/procemostrar'); ?>
                <label>Seleccione:  </label>
            <select name="agente" id="agente" class="form-control">
            <option value="100" >Select agente</option>
            <?php foreach($agentes as $agente):?>
            <option value="<?php echo $agente->iUsuario?>"
                <?php echo set_select('agente',$agente->iUsuario); ?> >
                 <?php echo $agente->Nombre?>
                 <?php echo $agente->iUsuario?>

            </option>
                <?php endforeach;?> </select>

                                <?php //echo "string",$fmax, $FechaMax; ?>


            <input type="text" id="dateone" name="dateone"  value="2017/06/1" />
            <input type="text" id="datetwo" name="datetwo" value="2017/06/28" />



        <!-- <div id="dateSlider" class="slider-purple"></div>-->

                                <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit"  class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 30px">
                                Buscar
                            </button>

                        </form>



                        <!-- end: PAGE TITLE & BREADCRUMB -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- end: PAGE HEADER -->
                <!-- start: PAGE CONTENT -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <!-- start: DYNAMIC TABLE PANEL -->
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">

                                <i class="fa fa-external-link-square"></i>
                                Reportes de usuario 
                                <div class="panel-tools">
                                    <a class="btn btn-xs btn-link panel-collapse collapses" href="#"> </a>


                                    <a class="btn btn-xs btn-link panel-close" href="#"> <i class="fa fa-times"></i> </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                    <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/datatables/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css')?>" rel="stylesheet"> 

        <table id="table" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th style="width: 5%;background-color: #006699; color: white;">iUsuario</th>
                  <th style="width: 10%;background-color: #006699; color: white;">Agente</th>
                  <th style="width: 10%;background-color: #006699; color: white;">Cliente</th>
                  <th style="width: 10%;background-color: #006699; color: white;">Disposition</th>
                  <th style="width: 10%;background-color: #006699; color: white;">FechaIns</th>
                  <th style="width: 10%;background-color: #006699; color: white;">Acción</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
          </table>


                                    </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- end: DYNAMIC TABLE PANEL -->
                    </div>
                </div>



                <!-- end: PAGE CONTENT-->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end: PAGE -->
    </div>


                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Estos scripts los tengo en la vista

```
var baseurl = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
</script>  

<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js')?>"></script>   
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/persona.js')?>"></script>  


<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('input[name="dateone"]').daterangepicker({

        locale: {
      format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
    },
        singleDatePicker: true,
        showDropdowns: true

    }, 
    function(start, end, label) {
        var years = $('#dateone').val();
        alert("You are " + years + " years old.");
    });
});
</script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('input[name="datetwo"]').daterangepicker({

        locale: {
      format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
    },
        singleDatePicker: true,
        showDropdowns: true

    }, 
    function(start, end, label) {
        var years = $('#datetwo').val();
        alert("You are " + years + " years old.");
    });
});

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$('#submit').click(function(){

var agente          =   $('#agente').val();
var dateone         =   $('#dateone').val();
var datetwo         =   $('#datetwo').val();




$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/reports/getPersonas2",
        data:{
            'agente':       agente,
            'dateone':      dateone,
            'datetwo':      datetwo

        }, 

        success:function (data) {
            alert("Los datos fueron agregados con exito");


        },error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log('error:: '+ errorThrown);
        }

    });
});
```

Mi modelo

```
<?php
class Reports_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function getTabla(){
        $this->db->select('iUsuario,Agente,Cliente,Disposition,FechaIns');
        $this->db->from('v_CallUser');
        $r = $this->db->get();
        return $r->result();
    }

    public function shearchdinamic($info){
            $this->db->select('iUsuario,Agente,Cliente,Disposition,FechaIns');
            $this->db->where('FechaIns',$info['fmin']);
            $this->db->where('FechaIns',$info['nombre']);
            $this->db->from('v_CallUser');
            $r = $this->db->get();
        return $r->result();
        }
}
?>
```

Mi controlador

```
public function getPersonas(){
        echo json_encode($this->Reports_model->getTimeZone());
    }
    public function getPersonas2(){
        echo json_encode($this->Reports_model->shearchdinamic($info));
    }

    public function procemostrar(){
        $data  = $this->input->post();  
            echo "string<br><br><br><br>". $data['agente'].$data['dateone'].$data['datetwo'];
        //$id = $this->input->post('agente');  
        $datar = array(
                'agentes' => $this->Usuarios_model->Consultan2()
          ); 
        $info = array(
                'iUsuario'      =>  $data['agente'],
                'fmin'          =>  $data['dateone'],
                'fmax'          =>  $data['datetwo']
          ); 

       //$this->Reports_model->shearchdinamic($info);

        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->view('_partials/_header');     
        $this->load->view('_reportes/_reporte_porusuario',$datar);     
        $this->load->view('_partials/_footer'); 


    }
}
```

Y un *js* que tengo separado para llenar la tabla

```
$('#table').DataTable({
    'paging': true,
    'info': true,
    'filter': true,
    'stateSave': true,

      'ajax': {
        "url":baseurl+"index.php/reports/getPersonas/",
        "type":"POST",
         dataSrc: ''},
      'columns': [
        {data: 'iUsuario'},
        {data: 'Agente'},
        {data: 'Cliente'},
        {data: 'Disposition'},
        {data: 'FechaIns'},
    {"orderable": true,
     render:function(data, type, row){
        return   '<a href="#" class= "btn btn-block btn-primary btn-sm"></a>'

          }
        }
       ],
      "order": [[1 , "asc" ]],
    });
```

Comment: Me podran ayudar , separado si puedo hacer la consulta sin enviar parametros y tambien puedo enviar los parametros al controlador pero cuando quiero hacer la consulta enviando esos parametros al modelo tengo ese error.

Comment: Hola rodrigo yo actualmente hago algo parecido trabajo con CI, y tambien tengo mi tabla donde el usuario busca de forma dinamica, es decir por rango de fecha o por nombre o por fecha, pero para ayuidarte solo necesito saber tu html de tu tabla el controlador de tu llenado y el modelo

Comment: ok enseguida lo pongo

Comment: Lo que no se es como enviar y recibir datos a la ves por la misma petición ajax, por que los dos scrips funcionan pero por separado, uno para enviar los datos de la vista al controlador que serian las fechas y el nombre por los que deseo buscar,  y el otro para llenar la tabla también funciona.  Pero para enviar esos parametros por donde relleno la tabla como le aria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actualmente trabajo con CI y hago lo mismo que tu en mi caso no necesito el boton buscar, TRABAJO CON algunos atributos en mi vista como`data-column` y eso te ayudara mas eso hago en mi vista y aparte solo declaro la tabla, en JQuery utilizo `.search-input-text` eso me ayuda con la busqueda, en mi controlador armo `array` y ya con eso lleno la tabla por otro lado en el modelo hago una busqueda por `columns` te dejo cada parte del CI espero te ayude :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**NO OLVIDES COLOCAR ESTO EN LA PARTE INFERIOR DE TU VISTA**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                                        var baseurl = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
                                        var ciCsrfToken = "<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>";
    </script>
```

**VISTA :**

```
<!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <section class="content-header">
                    <h1>
                        Listado de Ventas
                    </h1>
                </section>
                <!-- Main content -->
                <section class="content">
                    <div class="box box-solid box-primary">
                        <div class="box-header with-border">
                            <h6 class="box-title"><i class="fa fa-calendar-check-o"></i> BUSQUEDA </h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-body">
                            <div class="box-body">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-horizontal">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="form-horizontal">                                        
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label class="control-label col-md-4">FECHA INICIO</label>
                                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                                            <input data-column="1" id="bfecha_inicio" value=""
                                                                   class="form-control datepicker search-input-text" readonly
                                                                   type="text"> <span class="help-block"></span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label class="control-label col-md-4">FECHA FINAL</label>
                                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                                            <input data-column="2" id="bfecha_final" value=""
                                                                   class="form-control datepicker search-input-text" readonly
                                                                   type="text"> <span class="help-block"></span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label class="control-label col-md-4">CLIENTE</label>
                                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                                            <input data-column="3" id="cliente" value=""
                                                                   class="search-input-text form-control" style="width: 100%">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>                                        
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <br>
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <div class="box box-solid box-primary">
                                <div class="box-header">
                                    <h3 class="box-title">
                                        <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> LISTADO DE VENTAS
                                    </h3>

                                </div>
                                <br>

                                <hr>
                                <!-- /.box-header -->
                                <div class="box-body">                        
                                    <table id="tabla_ventas"
                                           class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover responsive"
                                           cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                        <thead class="background-thead">
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Nº</th>
                                                <th>CLIENTE</th>
                                                <th>TOTAL</th>
                                                <th style="width: 200px;">FEHA</th>
                                                <th>DETALLE</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

**EN MI JQUERY**

```
    var comprobante;

$(document).ready(function () {

    $(function () {

        tabla_ventas = $('#tabla_ventas').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "order": [],

            "ajax": {
                "url": baseurl + 'Caja/listar_ventas',
                "type": "POST",
                "data": {"ci_csrf_token": ciCsrfToken}
            },

            "columnDefs": [
                {
                    "targets": [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3],
                    "orderable": false
                }
            ],
            "language": {
                "processing": "Procesando...",
                "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                "zeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
                "emptyTable": "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
                "info": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
                "infoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
                "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                "infoPostFix": "",
                "search": "Buscar:",
                "url": "",
                "infoThousands": ",",
                "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                "paginate": {
                    "first": "Primero",
                    "last": "Último",
                    "next": "Siguiente",
                    "previous": "Anterior"
                },
                "aria": {
                    "sortAscending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                    "sortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
                }
            },
            "lengthMenu": [[10, 15, 20, 25], [10, 15, 20, 25]],
            "iDisplayLength": 10,
        });



        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
            todayHighlight: true,
            orientation: "top auto",
            todayBtn: true,
            todayHighlight: true,
            language: "es"
        });


        $('.search-input-text').on('keyup click', function () {
            var i = $(this).attr('data-column');
            var v = $(this).val();
            tabla_ventas.columns(i).search(v).draw();
        });


        $('.search-input-select').on('change', function () {
            var i = $(this).attr('data-column');
            var v = $(this).val();
            tabla_ventas.columns(i).search(v).draw();
        });

        $('#bfecha_inicio').on('change', function () {   // for select box
            var i = $(this).attr('data-column');
            var v = $(this).val();
            tabla_ventas.columns(i).search(v).draw();
        });

        $('#bfecha_final').on('change', function () {   // for select box
            var i = $(this).attr('data-column');
            var v = $(this).val();
            tabla_ventas.columns(i).search(v).draw();
        });
    });
});
```

**EN MI CONTROLADOR**

```
public function listar_ventas() {
        $pagos = $this->caja->obtener_data_pagos();
        $data = array();
        $no = $_POST ['start'];
        foreach ($pagos as $pago) {
            $no ++;
            $row = array();
            $row [] = '<div class="text-left">' . 'VEN000' . $pago->id_venta . '</div>';
            $row [] = $pago->nombres_completos;
            $row [] = $pago->total;
            $row [] = $pago->fecha_venta;
            $row [] = '<div onclick="detalle_venta(' . $pago->id_venta . ')" class="text-center details-control"><a><i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-2x"></i></a></div>';
            $data [] = $row;
        }
        $output = array(
            "draw" => $_POST ['draw'],
            "recordsTotal" => $this->caja->contador_total_pagos(),
            "recordsFiltered" => $this->caja->contador_filtrado_pagos(),
            "data" => $data
        );
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
```

**EN MODELO**
"COMO OBSERVACION 'v_ventas' es la vista creada en mysql"

```
var $t_view_pagos = 'v_ventas';
    var $query_pagos = null;

    private function _obtener_data_query_pagos() {

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $this->t_view_pagos;
        $sql .= " WHERE 1 = 1 ";

        if (!empty($_POST ['columns'] [1] ['search'] ['value'])) { // Fecha inicial
            $sql .= " AND fecha_venta >= '" . date_format(date_create($_POST ['columns'] [1] ['search'] ['value']), "Y-m-d") . "' ";
        }

        if (!empty($_POST ['columns'] [2] ['search'] ['value'])) { // Fecha final
            $sql .= " AND fecha_venta <= '" . date_format(date_create($_POST ['columns'] [2] ['search'] ['value']), "Y-m-d") . "' ";
        }

        if (!empty($_POST ['columns'] [3] ['search'] ['value'])) { // Cliente
            $sql .= " AND nombres_completos like '" . $_POST ['columns'] [3] ['search'] ['value'] . "%' ";
        }

        $this->query_pagos = $sql;
        if ($_POST ['length'] != - 1)
            $sql .= "LIMIT " . $_POST ['start'] . ", " . $_POST ['length'];
        return $sql;
    }

    function obtener_data_pagos() {
        $sql = $this->_obtener_data_query_pagos();
        $query = $this->db_caja->query($sql);
        return $query->result();
    }

    function contador_filtrado_pagos() {
        $query = $this->db_caja->query($this->query_pagos);
        return $query->num_rows();
    }

    public function contador_total_pagos() {
        $this->db_caja->from($this->t_view_pagos);
        return $this->db_caja->count_all_results();
    }
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias Ivan, funciono perfectamente

Comment: Ya con esto dominas las DataTable en CI (Y) suerte